# Java code doesn't compile or run

Tags: java

I'm begginer to Java and I'm doing my first baby steps in this language. I just watched a tutorial and tried to code something basic. Everything seemed fine, no warnings or errors, but my code just doesn't compile or work, when I press run just nothing happens. Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class pagrindinis {
    private String name;
    private int Id;
    private int Age;
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

public void Gyvunas() {
    System.out.println("Animal:");
    this.setName(userInput.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Age?:");
    this.setAge(userInput.nextInt());
    System.out.println("Animal is " + name + ", " + " age is " + Age + ", " + "animal ID is " + Id);

}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }

        public String getName() {
             return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;       
        }

        public int getId() {
            return Id;
        }

        public void setId(int Id) {
            this.Id = Id;

        System.out.println("Animal ID is - " + this.Id);
        }

        public void setId() {
            this.Id = (int) Math.random()*(10-1)+1;
        }
        public int getAge() {
            return Age;
        }
        public void setAge(int Age) {
            this.Age = Age;
        }
}
```

Any ideas? I'm pretty sure it's something silly, but I still can't manage to do it. Thank you!

Comment: because your main() is empty.

Answer (score 2):

Your code compiles well. If it didn't compile, you'd have errors.

And it also runs. But your `main` method is empty, so it doesn't do anything.

In Java, the program runs whatever is written in the `main` method. If there is nothing, then the program will do nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Try call the method you want.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
      Gyvunas();
    }
```

For your information there are certain conventions that you seem to violate. The method name should start with lowercase and Class name should start with Uppercase. Please follow this [code naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) for more details.